# How to read csv file into dictionary without using any advanced module instead of csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Can only use CSV as advanced modules, how do I convert the following data into a dictionary? The first row(header) has to be the key for the dictionary. So far I only found the method to read the first column as the key.

```
DB,Field1,Field2,Field3
A,DataF1,DataF2,DataF3
B,MoreDataF1,MoreDataF2,MoreDataF3
C,SomeMoreDataF1,SomeMoreDataF2,SomeMoreDataF3
```

This is my work did currently:

```
import csv
dict_from_csv = {}
    with open('library-titles.csv', mode='r') as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    dict_from_csv = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
```

This is my expected output:

```
[{'DB': 'A',
 'Field1': 'DataF1',
 'Field2': 'DataF2',
 'Field3': 'DataF3'},

 {'DB': 'B',
 'Field1': 'MoreDataF1',
 'Field2': 'MoreDataF2',
 'Field3': 'MoreDataF3'}]
```

Comment: There's a reason the `csv` module exists - it will handle edge cases that you never thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read a csv file by opening it through the conventional way: `open()`. Then, create a list with lines. Then, `split(',')` each line.

```
#first load the file
csv_file = open(file_path, 'r')

#then collect the lines
file_lines = csv_file.readlines()

#remove the '\n' at the end of each line
file_lines = [line[:-1] for line in file_lines]

#collect the comma separated values into lists
table = [line.split(',') for line in file_lines]
```

Now you have a `table` which traduces your csv file, in which the header row is `table[0]`. You can now handle the data contained in the csv file, and convert it into a list of dictionaries:

```
dict_list = []
for line in table[1:]: #exclude the header line
    dict_from_csv = {}
    for i, elem in enumerate(line):
        dict_from_csv[table[0][i]] = elem #for each line elem, associate it to its header relative
    dict_list.append(dict_from_csv)
```

That is it. Of course, you can compress it all into few lines through list and dictionary comprehension:

```
with open(filepath,'r') as csv_file:
    table = [strline[:-1].split(',') for strline in csv_file.readlines()]
    dict_list = [{table[0][i]:elem for i, elem in enumerate(line)} for line in table[1:]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the method provided. But it is still displayed that the first column in the table is a key. I have added my expected output in the questions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I modified the second part of my answer to fit your expectations. It now does return the expected output.

Comment: Yes, but if I'm not mistaken according to your answer, the output will show in list mode right? (since you use the dict_list to append). Is there is any way to put all data inside a dictionary and do some operations with the dictionary function without using the list to append it?

Comment: I am not sure what you want. Do you want the output to be dictionary of dictionaries? Or do you want to reach the final output from a dictionary?

Comment: Just ignore what I'm saying haha. Realised that the dictionary cannot include duplicate keys. Thanks for your answer help me a lot!

Comment: It was a pleasure! Note that you can use a dictionary instead of a list as an output. Each dictionary would be associated to a key, something like: `dict[id]`. Thought, it comes to be the same as using a list if you use indexes as keys: `list[id]`.